# GET request with body is not working on flutter web

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-web

I have a GET request where I need to pass some data as a body. I know its not right, but I cannot change it. I tried it on postman and api is working fine. Then I used postman's code generator to get dart http code. But that code is working on the mobile only, not on the flutter web. Here is the code -

```
var headers = {
  "content-type": "application/json",
};
var request = http.Request("GET", Uri.parse("https://<domain>/path"));
request.body = json.encode({
  source: 10,
});
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
} else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

Comment: What version of `http` are you using?

Comment: latest version - http 0.13.5

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Running into this issue as well.

Comment: Sadly no.. i even tried frm root web folder using javascript, but no result.